# How do I change the order in which grep looks at files/prints results?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, gnu

I have a directory with a bunch of files with numerical filenames. They don't have leading zeroes, so if I do something like `grep hello *` in that directory I might get something like this:

```
22:hello, world!
6:hello
62:"Say hello to them for me."
```

I'd rather have the result be like this:

```
6:hello
22:hello, world!
62:"Say hello to them for me."
```

The first thought that occured to me was to sort the results numerically with `grep hello * | sort -n` but then I lose grep's colors, which I'd like to keep. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: I suggest changing the title to "how not lose color in grep" or something like that. Keep the current title inside the question text(description). This way, people will not incorrectly redirect questions here. It is better for community s it is a question that comes high in searches.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ls * | sort -n | xargs -d '\n' grep hello
```

Comment: Thanks! So what that xargs command does is take standard input, split it by newlines, and then append the results to "grep hello" as arguments, then?

Comment: @pandubear Yes, exactly. Couldn't have said it better.

Comment: you can also add `-H` option to `grep` to print the filename for each match (to have same output as `grep -R`)

Comment: @ShichengGuo Could you post that as a new question?

Comment: For me `sort --version-sort` worked better, so @JohnKugelman command would be `ls * | sort --version-sort | xargs -d '\n' grep hello`

Answer (score 4):

Ah -- `grep` suppresses its colors when its output is a pipe (which is probably a good thing). But this can be overridden by supplying `--color=always`, which makes the `| sort -n` approach work:

```
grep --color=always hello * | sort -n
```